# Tensorflow lite model gives false values using MLKit firebase

Tags: java, python, android, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

I have posted many questions related to my problem but I didn't get any answer.
I'm really new to machine learning domain and Tensorflow.
I'm working on a project that detects eye region with landmarks on Android device.
My problem is when I integrate the TensorFlow lite model on Android using MLKit firebase api, I get false and differents values to what I get from frozen inference model.
I have tried to test on the image from the ibug dataset and I tried to print results using `print` on python and `log.i()` on java (Android), but values are so different.

I doubt that the problem is related to the model, but unfortunately no.
The reason is that I have tested the Tensorflow lite model with a python script and I get same values that I get from the frozen inference model.

This is the difference :

**+ The result from the inference frozen model:**

[image: Result from frozen model]

**+ The result from the Tensorflow lite model:**

[image]

some of the code that I used:

```java
private float[][][][] bitmapToInputArray() {
        // [START mlkit_bitmap_input]
        orgbitmap= getYourInputImage();
        Bitmap bite = orgbitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int batchNum = 0;
        float[][][][] input = new float[1][112][112][3];
        for (int x = 0; x < 112; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < 112; y++) {
                int pixel = bite.getPixel(x, y);
                // Normalize channel values to [-1.0, 1.0]. This requirement varies by
                // model. For example, some models might require values to be normalized
                // to the range [0.0, 1.0] instead.
                input[batchNum][x][y][0] = (Color.red(pixel))/ 255.0f;
                input[batchNum][x][y][1] = (Color.green(pixel)) / 255.0f;
                input[batchNum][x][y][2] = (Color.blue(pixel)) / 255.0f;
                Log.i("Input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y][0]);
                Log.i("input","input"+input[batchNum][x][y][1]);

            }
        }
        // [END mlkit_bitmap_input]

        return input;
    }

 private void runInference() throws FirebaseMLException {
        FirebaseModelInterpreter firebaseInterpreter = createInterpreter();
        float[][][][] input = bitmapToInputArray();
        FirebaseModelInputOutputOptions inputOutputOptions = createInputOutputOptions();
        Bitmap bittmp=getYourInputImage();
        // [START mlkit_run_inference]
        FirebaseModelInputs inputs = new FirebaseModelInputs.Builder()
                .add(input)  // add() as many input arrays as your model requires
                .build();

        firebaseInterpreter.run(inputs, inputOutputOptions)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseModelOutputs>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseModelOutputs result) {
                                try {
                                    //String[] results= new String[40];
                                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                                    // [START mlkit_read_result]
                                    float[][] output = result.getOutput(0);
                                    float[] probabilities = output[0];
                                    Log.i("Prob",""+probabilities);
                                    float[][][][] input2=bitmapToInputArray();
                                    Log.i("input values",""+input2);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "probalitities: " + probabilities + "  output: " + output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    useInferenceResult(probabilities);

                                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+results, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    // [END mlkit_read_result]
                                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                                }
                                catch (Exception es){
                                    Log.e("Error",""+es);
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+es.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // Task failed with an exception
                                // ...
                            }
                        });
        // [END mlkit_run_inference]
private void useInferenceResult(float[] probabilities) throws IOException {
        // [START mlkit_use_inference_result]
        String[] result=new String[80];
        ArrayList<Point> listpoint= new ArrayList<Point>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; i++) {

                Log.i("MLKit", String.format("%1.8f", probabilities[i]));
                x = String.format("%1.8f", probabilities[i]);
                y = String.format("%1.8f", probabilities[i+1]);           
                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                p.setX(x);
                p.setY(y);
                listpoint.add(p);
                Log.i("Point avant","  "+p.getX());
                Log.i("Point avant2","  "+p.getY());
                i=i+1;
         }
    }
 }
 btn_open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 

                configureLocalModelSource();
                try {

                    firebaseModelInterpreter = createInterpreter();
                    configureLocalModelSource();
                    runInference();

                }
                catch (FirebaseMLException exs){
                    Log.e("Erreur",exs.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+exs.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
 private Bitmap getYourInputImage() {
        // This method is just for show
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image2.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmapp = drawable.getBitmap();
        Bitmap bitmap2=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,112,112,true);
        return bitmap2;
       // return Bitmap.createBitmap(112, 112, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    }
}
```

Logs of python script ( correct values ):

> 0.33135968 0.19592011 0.34212315 0.17297666 0.36624995 0.16413747
> 0.3894139  0.17440952 0.39828074 0.1978043  0.3891497  0.22268474
> 0.36345637 0.22974193 0.3401759  0.2193309  0.30167252 0.20411113
> 0.3167112  0.19134495 0.33793524 0.18388326 0.3642417  0.18049955
> 0.3903508  0.18533507 0.40906873 0.1957745  0.42142123 0.21091096
> 0.40550107 0.21829814 0.38345626 0.22071144 0.35900232 0.22142673
> 0.3363348  0.21877256 0.3161971  0.2133534  0.62843406 0.21482795
> 0.6389724  0.1914106  0.6628249  0.1835615  0.6858679  0.19583184
> 0.6946868  0.22111627 0.6840309  0.24444285 0.66027373 0.25241333
> 0.6351568  0.24192403 0.60499936 0.22642238 0.6210091  0.21289764
> 0.6423563  0.2042976  0.6685919  0.20277795 0.69201195 0.20948553
> 0.70882106 0.22015369 0.71931773 0.23518339 0.7076659  0.24166131
> 0.69054717 0.24350837 0.6694564  0.24258481 0.64537776 0.23927754
> 0.62199306 0.23511863

Logs of java Android (false values):

> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.421 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant:   0,22430149
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.421 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant2:   0,36553931
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.422 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant:   0,23864979
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.423 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant2:   0,32543975
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.424 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant:   0,27703676
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.424 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant2:   0,30710658
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.429 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant:   0,31750143
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.429 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant2:   0,32192159
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.431 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant:   0,33583546
>
> 2019-09-17 14:37:20.431 4991-4991/com.example.irisdetection I/Point avant2:   0,36056906

What is the problem in this code?

Comment: Dividing each pixel value by 255 will normalize the pixel value in range [ 0 , 1 ].

Comment: To bring the values in range [ -1 , 1 ], use `( pixel - 127.5 ) / 127.5`.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't have any idea about normalization and image processing can you explain to me, how do you know that the range is [-1, 1]?

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me.